# xml - How to convert Windows Phone 8.1 layout to Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, windows-phone-8.1

here's my Windows Phone layout...

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

My question is: How to achieve this type of layout in android?

**What i expect:** I want two sections in android. First section will contain editboxes and will be scrollable and 2nd section will contain a button only and I want it to show always. Mean it will not scroll with the form.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not all of use will be familiar with windows phone, this sounds like a grid layout. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: ofcourse this question is not for all SO users :) only users who know android and wp programming both

Comment: I have added screenshot of wp application page that I have made using this type of grid

Comment: Then why don't you add the tag for windows phone so those who are familiar are more likely to see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want 2nd row to take space according to its items inside it and rest of space should be given to first row.

In that case it is down to the children to decide how much space they take as the grid view just defines the overall container for all items

```
<GridLayout android:id="@+id/the_grid"
            android:rowCount="2" android:columnCount="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <TextView  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <TextView  android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

</GridLayout>
```

Alternatively, you may find it works better with linear layouts, but then in order to make sure the top row stays as a row, you would have to use fixed height

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="56dp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView  android:layout_height="56dp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        <TextView  android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: I want 2nd row to take space according to its items inside it and rest of space should be given to first row. Hope you understand.

Comment: *I want 2nd row to take space...* : you seem to be wanting a lot of things for someone who doesn't seem to have tried anything for himself before asking the question ...

Comment: well its not exactly what I want. But give me a hint so thanks